# Where is the fishing scene in My Neighbour Totoro?

Tags: my-neighbor-totoro

On the box for the DVD and Blu-ray versions of *My Neighbour Totoro*, there is a picture of the characters from the film fishing with Mei catching a crab. We love the image but cannot find the scene in the movie. Where does this scene come from?

[image: The "My Neighbor Totoro" fishing scene]

Comment: Anyone planning a trip to the Ghibli Museum soon?

Answer (score 3):

I may have the answer. It appears that this was never a scene that actually occurred in the movie at all in My Neighbour Totoro (The Movie). It was actually.....

> A promotional art for the movie My Neighbour Totoro

I came to the conclusion when I watched the movie myself three times for clarification and asked some of my friends who helped me research a bit.

Comment: i have no idea about this but maybe it must part of extended version for dvd only .

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure about this ever. I actually haven't watched My Neighbour Totoro the movie before. I was watching it with my friends a couple days ago to try find out the answer for this question.

Comment: So strange, you would think there would be some reference to this somewhere online. My DVD and blue ray box set does not have this scene in it anywhere, even in the extras except on the front cover of the box

Comment: I haven't got the DVD box set, When I watched it I ended up just streaming it online. But I did eventually end up buying a digital copy. This question stumped me because I can't find anything of use to add to my answer due to limited information.